# Ubuntu changed to Read-only file system after update & rbenv install

Tags: mount, updates, filesystem, ruby, read-only

Linux noob using Ubuntu 20.04.3 to learn code.

Background: This morning I was prompted by Ubuntu to install updates and restart. I have been installing `rbenv` and Ruby Gems this week trying to fix my development environment (I had previously installed Ruby via `sudo apt` and it was causing havoc). I had `rbenv` working fine and it was setting the global version of Ruby to the correct latest version, but I had to `source ~/.bash_profile` in order to prepend the shims correctly, otherwise it would default to the ruby installed by `apt`. I also did `sudo apt upgrade` from the terminal before installing rbenv and it all worked fine for 3 days until I did the update/restart I was prompted to.

Now, chaos.

Trying to `source ~/.bash_profile` I get he following error:

```
/usr/lib/rbenv/libexec/rbenv-init: line 131: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system
```

Trying to save any files using the GUI I get

```
Failed to save 'GREED_RULES.txt': Unable to write file '/home/vida/Desktop/koans/GREED_RULES.txt' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/home/vida/Desktop/koans/GREED_RULES.txt')
```

Tried `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda5` and get
`mount: /: cannot remount /dev/sda5 read-write, is write-protected.`

My etc/fstab is

```
/etc/fstab: static file system information.
Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/ was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a0f66c38-8b52-4d2f-87f2-a8ef1e49796b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A88E-FD34  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw
```

I've looked at a bunch of other questions like this but they are generally 5-8 years old and using virtual machines, this is a fairly fresh installation and the only OS on this machine.

Comment: Often when a filesystem becomes ReadOnly it is because of a software or hardware error. Try booting up on a live media (USB, DVD ..) and run `fsck -y /dev/sda5` to check and repair the root FS. You can also take a look at /var/log/syslog for disk errors around the time when the FS became ReanOnly.

Comment: This worked well enough! Took a bit of work to reboot successfully (had ncq issues) but ultimately resolved it. Thanks!